# What would be the equivalent of title = $(element).find('h3').text() if I'm trying to find and send a link that has an href tag in front of it?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, cheerio

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that gets the most recent post and sends it out when someone runs a command. I've managed to make it work by sending out the titles of the posts, but I want to make it so that it sends out the link to the post.

The HTML of the forum for the post looks something like

`<a href="/x/y/random numbers and letters" class="post_link"></a>`

Is there any way to get those random numbers and letters from the HTML element and apply them to a link somewhere else in the bot's code? I tried using puppeteer and cheerio to do this but I can't figure out what the `title = $(element).find('XXXXXXXXXXX').text()` would be.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `cheerio`, you'll want to do something like this:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load('<a href="https://link-here.com/a/b/c" class="post_link"></a>');

const href = $('a').attr('href');
// "https://link-here.com/a/b/c"
```